# stairwell or staircase

Tags: meaning

What is the word for the building where the stairs are located stairwell or staircase or stairway?
Is that in the image stairwell or staircase or stairway?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A stairwell is a shaft that contains, or has been built to contain, a staircase. The image shows a staircase and its bannister, but part of the stairwell is visible as well (the tiled wall).

Comment: It's a balustrade not a bannister

Comment: @Stevetech, it's generally a bannister in the US.

Comment: Note that not every staircase need be located inside a stairwell.  A single flight of stairs such as may be found in a 2-story house, for example, is not.  A stairwell is typically separated from the rest of the building (e.g. by doors on each landing).  They are often not heated/air conditioned.  They generally run from the bottom to top of a building or section of building, spanning more than 2 floors.  (Taller skyscrapers may not have a single stairwell all the way up, depending on design.)

Comment: @Stevetech In my experience growing in the UK, `banister` was the more correct term. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baluster#Banisters), `balustrade` is a more general term to mean any kind of railing.  When specifically applied to stairs, `banister` appears to be the more correct term.

Comment: This makes sense, but I'd like to point out that I'm a native speaker (AmE) and I don't make a huge distinction between any of these words. I usually just call the "stairs" or "stairwell".

Comment: Also staircases on the outside of buildings (eg fire stairs) don't have a stairwell